# How to Move all subfolders of assets folder in to sdcard in android

Tags: android

I have made an application, in which I am using more images & videos , I have putted all of resources inside the sub folders of assets & also my database is in a sub folder of assets folder, I want to move whole sub folders of assets folder including there files in sdcard.
My assets folder size is more than 30mb.

Comment: You cannot "move" them as the assets pseudo-folder is read only to your application, but you can copy them (leaving the originals in place) as multiple answers describe below.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can access assest is throw assetManager to get input steream from them.

So your code will have to look something like this.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length ; i++) {
        try{
         InputStream is = aManager.open(files[i]);
         OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(output[i]);
         read = 0;
         buffer = new byte[1024];
         while (read != -1) {
              read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
               if (read == -1)
                    break;
               os.write(buffer, 0, read);
          }
       } finally {
              is.close();
              os.close();
    }}
```

where files is an array of Strings to the pathes in your asset folder , and output is an array of strings of pathes to the output directory "on SD card "

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to copy assets folders & files into sdcard.

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + filename);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }       
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Reference : [Move file using Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/MoveaFile.htm)